# My source is in order, is yours?

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source

Your challenge is to write a program, function, etc. that calculates if the passed string is "in order". That means that the characters of the string have character codes that are in order from smallest to largest.  The smallest char code must be the first. By that I mean lowest unicode codepoints to highest. It doesn't matter what code page you language uses.

You must return one value if the input is "in order" and another if it is not. The values must be distinct, but there is no other restriction on the output values. For example, you may print/return/output `true` for `!1AQaq¡±` (in order) and `false` for `aq!QA`.  The two distinct values don't need to be truthy or falsy or anything like that, just two distinct values. Repeated strings (eg. `aa`) are in order.

You only need to support up to unicode `U+007E` (`~`) (ascii 126)

However, the characters of your program must itself be in order. Good luck and happy [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)ing!

Comment: You don't need to have truthy/falsy values? two truthys would work?

Comment: Also, is the smallest char code always at the first char? Or can it be reversed?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "UTF-8 character". You probably just mean "the characters of the strings have character codes that are in order from smallest to largest".

Comment: @RIker the values have to be distinct. It says that.

Comment: @programmer5000 yes, but you don't need 1 falsy and 1 truthy?

Comment: @Riker no, just 2 distinct values. `2` and `3` would work.

Comment: Code-golf honestly seems like a poor win condition for this form of restricted source. Code bowling for most unique characters would be more interesting.

Comment: @fəˈnɛtɪk interesting idea, but then in a lot of langs it amounts to doing it in the lowest code points possible, then fitting in as much garbage as possible. My choice for this would be pop-con.

Comment: @Pavel Pop cons don't work well for achieving a particular task in a particular way.

Comment: is repeated string in order? for example, is `"aa"` in order?

Comment: By what standard do characters need to be 'in order' in the source code? By Unicode codepoints, or in their own codepages? Point in case: Jelly (`Ṣ⁼` vs `⁼Ṣ`).

Comment: @steenbergh see edit.

Comment: Is the empty string a valid input?

Comment: @Aaron technically no, but I won't require you to support it.

Comment: OK, who is downvoting?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 2 bytes

```
.o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@6@X//@/UmJqZn6pEgA)

### Explanation

```
.o
.   Assert that {the input} equals the output of the last command in the program
 o  Sort {the input}
```

As a full program, an assertion failure gives `false.`, any successful run that doesn't violate any assertions gives `true.`

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 bytes

```
Ṣ⁼
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/9w56JHjXv@//@vlJiamV@qBAA)

### Explanation

```
Ṣ⁼
Ṣ    Sort {the input}
 ⁼   Compare that to {the input} for equality of the whole structure
```

`⁼Ṣ` also has the right functionality ("compare the input to the sorted input"), so it was just a case of running the two programs on themselves to figure out which was in order (I certainly don't have the Unicode codepoints of this part of Jelly's weird character set memorized).

Comment: Your submission is wrong in Jelly encoding, it needs to be `⁼Ṣ` instead. You can see Jelly's codepage [here](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page).

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer That is easily fixed; `⁼Ṣ` does exactly the same as `Ṣ⁼`.

Comment: @steenbergh This submission, as it is right now, is invalid. Even though the fix is easy, it hasn't been applied yet, and it's discouraged for others to edit code.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Discussion about this answer is mainly about which codepage to use: the challenge references Unicode (though doesn't explicitly tell us to use it) and Jelly has its own codepage. Whatever the outcome, fixing this answer is trivial. Therefor, I wouldn't go as far as calling this answer 'invalid' - I wouldn't even downvote it in its current state.

Comment: @steenbergh I haven't downvoted either, I was just notifying ais523 :)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer OP just edited challenge and specified Unicode as 'the order of things'. This answer seems to be valid, then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57107/discussion-between-erik-the-outgolfer-and-steenbergh).

Answer (score 8):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
GGS\a
```

Outputs `0` if input is in order, `1` otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@@/uHhyT@P@/ekhGZrFCcUlRZl66ApCVl1@ikJmnkF@UklqkDgA)

#### Explanation

This computes the modulus of (the code points of) each char from the input with that at the same index in the sorted input. The input is in order if and only if all results are `0`.

For example, consider the input string `BCD!`. Sorting it gives `'!BCD`. The arrays of code points are respectively `[66 67 68 33]` and `[33 66 67 68]`. Computing the moduli gives `[0 1 1 33]`, so the input is not in order. Note how some results can be `0` even if the values were not the same (here that happens at the first position), but that cannot happen in *all* entries unless the input is in order.

```
G     % Push input string
GS    % Push input string and sort it
\     % Modulus, element-wise. This gives all zeros iff the input was in order
a     % Any: gives 1 if any entry is non-zero. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>3</s> 2 bytes

```
{å
```

Thanks to Kevin for cutting out 33% of my source code!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/@vDS//9dgCQA)

Explanation:

```
      There used to be a D here for 'Duplicate stack' 
      but we now use the same input twice implicitly
 {    Sort the copy
  å   Check if the sorted copy is a substring of the original
      This will only return 1 if the original input is sorted, 0 otherwise.
```

Comment: `D{Q` also works...

Comment: @NeilA.It might do the same, but the characters are not in order. Requirement is that your source code passes the same test as the data does. [This should yield 1](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@9SfXjp//8u1YEA).

Comment: The `D` can be removed for -1 by just using an implicit input twice.

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 2 bytes

```
Sq
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyke#@x9c@P9/cCEA)

```
S  - sorted(input)
 q - ^ == input
```

Answer (score 4):

## [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 2 bytes

```
{Ê
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/2sable#@199uOv/fyPbQ4sPLT@85PDSw9sA)

**Explanation**

```
{    # sorted input
 Ê   # not equals (implicit input)
```

Outputs **0** if it is order, else **1**.

Comment: @steenbergh: Ah, missed that part of the challenge.

Comment: @steenbergh: Fixed! Fortunately we could output any distinct values :)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 2 bytes

```
<S
```

`False` means sorted, `True` means unsorted.

[Test suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%3CS&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22%3CS%22%0A%22%211AQaq%22%0A%22blah%22%0A%22aq%21QA%22&debug=0)

This was fairly nontrivial to come up with. The most obvious solution to this problem, without the restricted source, is `SI`, invariant under sorting. But that's not sorted. Then I thought of `qS`, which implicitly uses the input variable twice, checking if it's equal to its sorted self. But while `q < s`, `q > S`, so this didn't work either. But `<` comes before `S`, and the only way that the sorted version can not be less than the original is if the original was sorted, since the sorted version is the lexicographically minimal permutation of the elements.

Answer (score 1):

## [CGL (CGL Golfing Language)](https://codepen.io/programmer5000/pen/zwYrVd), 4 bytes

```
-:Sc
```

Explanation:

```
- Decrement the stack counter so the current stack is where input is put
: Split the first element of the current stack (input) into an array of single strings, make that the next stack, and increment the stack counter
S Sort the current stack
c Compare the current stack and the one before, push that to the next stack and increment the stack counter
(implicit) Output the first element of the current stack, true if in order, false if not.
```

Comment: Is there proof that this language was created before this challenge?

Comment: @KritixiLithos yes, and it is technically a valid language, but I will make this non-competing because the functions necessary to complete this were made after this challenge. CGL is still a work in progress, and I am using challenges to show me what new functions should be added.