# Is everything in order?

Tags: string, code-challenge, restricted-source, code-bowling

### Challenge:

**Input:** a string, consisting of only printable ASCII characters
**Output:** a truthy/falsey value whether its characters are in alphabetical order (based on their UTF-8 unicode values), from any starting point inside the string including wrap-around by going left-to-right

For example: `xyzabc` would give a truthy result, because we could travel `a→b→c→x→y→z`, but `xzy` would give a falsey result, because all possible starting points (`x→y→z`; `y→z→x`; `z→x→y`) are not in the correct order.

This sounds pretty simple, right? But there is one catch, as this is a [restricted-source](/questions/tagged/restricted-source) challenge: your program/function has to be in the correct order<sup>*†*</sup> as well.

<sup>*†: Based on the order of the characters in your own codepage. i.e. a program written in [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki) need to be (with the wraparound of course) in [the order of its own codepage](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page), instead of UTF-8 order.*</sup>

### Challenge rules:

- The input can be in any reasonable format. Can be a string, read from STDIN, a list of characters, etc. (No, you are not allowed to take a list of unicode values - which would basically be an integer list - unless your language does this conversion by default (i.e. Java (`char` only), Whitespace, etc.)
- The input is guaranteed to be printable ASCII (range \$[32,126]\$ / `[' ','~']`).
- If your program/function is written in a different codepage, it does not necessary have to hold a truthy value when used as input for itself. The source code does need to be in the correct order based on the used codepage of course.
- The input is guaranteed to be non-empty. (An input of one or two characters will always result in a truthy output.)
- The input (and your source) can contain multiple of the same characters.
- This is [code-bowling](/questions/tagged/code-bowling)[code-challenge](/questions/tagged/code-challenge), for which the longest answer counting only **distinct** bytes wins (i.e. if your source code is `ABBCabbc1223` your score would be 9 for `123ABCabc`).

### General rules:

- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test cases:

Truthy:

````
~
ab
ba
```
*5a
Test
test
xyzabc
aaabbbccc
aaabbbCCC
AAAbbbccc
msuwy !#),-./0123:;<?@BCFGILMNOQTWX]^_bf
oqqx}}~#$'''*+-./33489=?ABCHLQQQRTW[\]^_abcfgjkklmnno
````

Falsey:

```
xzy
C-U
TeSt
tesT
aaaBBBccc
M3"b=J7Uh:kg&F~\p`GLx?9#!%XCOZBv.m_)Y4V*
```

Comment: [related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/116426/my-source-is-in-order-is-yours)

Comment: IMHO I find it a bit too bad that a single rule disallows per se most programming languages and allows only cryptic-characters-languages-created-only-for-golfing, it could be more open by for example counting the longest ordered sequence in the code. (But that would mean not counting commented characters to prevent having the whole alphabet as a comment, even if that would damage a bit current aswer)

Comment: @Kaddath I can understand your standpoint and kinda agree, but I don't think banning comments would help, since we [don't have a clear definition of what a comment is](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12620/definition-of-a-comment). The current 05AB1E for example doesn't use any comments (in fact, the language doesn't even have comments), although there are still loads of no-ops which cancel each other out so only the code functionality remains. And not allowing no-ops kinda defeats the `[code-bowling]` part tbh.

Comment: I'm willing to change the challenge to allow more answers (if _Grimmy_ agrees), but it should require a clear definition of what is and isn't allowed. Currently I'm thinking of only allowing the 256 default characters of the used code-page perhaps (extended ASCII for most languages), so 256 would be the maximum score, and you can't for example score [137,929 by using all existing characters](https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/HowMany.html) in for example a Lenguage/Unary answer. And comments are then still allowed. But not sure if that's a good solution.

Comment: `(if Grimmy agrees)` I do. (Note that 256 is already the maximum score, since score is the number of distinct *bytes*).

Comment: @Grimmy Thanks for agreeing, but I'm still not really sure how to change the challenge. If I add that you have to maximize the largest portion of your used code page in your source code, everyone would just put all 256 bytes after one-another in a comment.. I.e. (used ASCII only as example) ``the source code # !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~``. I could ban comments, but what counts as a comment in that case? `"this is a comment"\ ` is what I sometimes add in my 05AB1E answers, but it's not really a comment.. Where to draw the line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>10</s> ... 172 distinct bytes

```
\]^_abcdefghiijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}}}~ƵƵ€Λ‚„…†‡ˆ‰ŠĆĆĆŽƶĀ‘‘’’““””••–—™š›œćŸā¡¢¢¢¤¤¦§¨©ª«¬®¯°±´¶·¸º»¼½½¾¿ÀÁÁÂÃÄÅÇÌÍÐÐÐÐÐÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷úü
 -.0123456789;<>@ABCDDDHKKOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TdDZMoJhHMfxc1fhBhj7MoyxdGCmA/s6lilCtpCdzFNSJ8yg0Eol7VpomxQz/19vJ2ZcxHMjyXtkPt8r@KrUMrlSUS7PzM7Ny@QLi4ql5RWlcnVtfWNTtbW9o97d2z84PDo@OdVoNGelVCnFdZEfO2c2zh4583Hm4sz9beAsLriKhj9CoZQuMs4sYlYxh5hTzCNm4szM9R7BzVlOMBWNQraoJTd5RN4KH/kpQEEKUZgiFKUYxSlBSUpThrKUow/KU6Hik77AoK3Q4Rx6XMCIS1zh@p8b3MIEM@5wjwdYYIUNdjjgxBNccMODZ3jxAj8CCCKEMCJ4RRQxxJHAG96RRAppZJBDvqq6prauvqGxqbmlta29o7Oru6e3TyKR9EulA4NDwyOjY@MTk1PT5XJl2y8) or [validate all test cases](https://tio.run/##RZFtU1JBFMff76dAqBhI6AFM8Qm5l9FKjVBQNBLuJVQiQAIRTJjVTN/UTIWVjwVkPpJiCTqkNbMHeNNMH2K/CF3u5DS/3@zs7JyZ/zlnAyGO97irM5GYXipRtUuk@hi8vqBqH3FwvOuRe3Rs3ON57H3i8wcmgk9D4cnIVDQ2/WwmHo8nKvlKns5l/6xRvErxR4q3KE5RnP69QHGunCot1CifVwolTPGy6IrouuiGaEY0SfESnc@U0xQXy8nSYvm0NEvSJCOyKbBFtskO2SV7ZJ9kyQE5JDlyRI5JgZyQU1IkP8gZORf4SX4BhlmBOXgO8/ACFuElvPo/mcAbeAtJWIJ38B4@wDKswCqswTpswCdIQRoy8Bk24Qtsww7swh5k4SscwCHk4Ai@wXc4hjwU4ASKcIYkKvX1Gzc12oZbjU26ltb2DgPDGo3G293dpvvmvn6LdWDQNjRcrVfYqwnE8YjnkNPpRMoGDlncoTAK1w5ho8KyEcdxPM@7XBc3lmWRwWD49@YLTU7FJHUyRb1Kfa2W2dzSqu9g2M6uOz2990xmy6Dt4YiDH0WBYDAq/I7sklwuV14VijUabZOuTW8wm819D@xCEef1@v0BFJ2OIVZlFRrpFxux1HIZhqml9WqkfNvdRut4s3fsSmfCPuHs6onqdbK6yzbWNMxE1D6HYkg7oPwL) (note: the "all test cases" version omits `]` and `ë`, since those don't play well with the header and footer required to run the code repeatedly).

Uses the [05AB1E code page](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage). [Validate restricted-source and scoring](https://tio.run/##TcLHTgJRGAbQvU8xYa3G3mMsszBhgb3FEsFRxwLKDHbMteFGExUbVsCuqFhAg6jJ/82wMfEh7osgzsqc41B6rLKUTOqfmmeW3kX4@k29sqLKdpsqWKdUSSkR8GVK1zwNQ4hnZFeIlrp22aQ4XE6bJDglRXXKNlV22AWL2ZSeTHZ0dnX3WG29Ul//gCwPDg2P2B2jY05FdY1PTE5Nz8y63e65RCQR4QuhnwPO9jk75uyCMz9ngW8PZ2Hdr3n@6B@JqMY42zP6jIfGI2PQ6OVsiy8F9QBnMd2rrehv2jwFKGg4S7mgS7qia7qhWwrRPT1QmB7phaL0Sm8Uo3eK00fKJ32BYT5lAYtYwjJWsIo1rP@zgU14sYVt7GAXe/BhHwc4xBFO4EcAQZziDOe4xBWucYNbhHCHezwgjEc84RkviCCKV8QQTxMyMrOyc3Lz8gsKi4pLy8orKquqRVGsMZsttXX1DY1NzS2tbe2/).

The useful code is just:

```
Ć            # append the first character of the input to the input
 Ç           # convert to a list of codepoints
  ü-         # pairwise subtraction
    1@       # >= 1?
      D      # duplicate
       O     # sum
        Q    # equal?
         Z   # maximum
```

The rest amounts to NOOPs.

Comment: Nice answer. I wasn't expecting that the entire alphabet (except for `q`) could be used as a no-op like that. :) [And I've verified that it's indeed correct for 05AB1E's codepage](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6L4jbZ7B2f//xyQmJaekpqVnZGZmZefk5uUXFBWXlJaVV1RWVdfU1tYeaTvcfniPrqGDi39gFAA), but you may want to explicitly mention it uses the custom 05AB1E codepage for challenges like this. Btw, you can add a few more no-ops between the `Q` and `Z`, like `R` and `S` for example, as well as `UX` or `VY`. :)

Comment: Actually `q` can be used as well, since it's within a non-executed `i}` anyway. And yeah, I'm not done bowling, there's still a ton of bytes to add.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I'm done with the low-hanging fruits. Of the 96 missing bytes, 46 are the bytes between `ü` and `-`, which can't be separated except by whitespace.